# Convert IEnumurable to Observable Collection without creating new instance of Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a **Observable Collection** which contains my data values. I want to use **Orderby** in that collection but i am getting some exception like 
`"Cannot convert IEnumurable to ObservableCollection"`.  Is there possible for using **OrderBy** or give me some options to **Sort the Collection** ?

Anyone please tell me the solution of this.
Thanks in advance.

My Code is:

```
get {

     return _availableStocks == null ? null : _availableStocks .OrderBy(z => z.Casepack.CasePackContents);   
     // Here _availableStocks is my collection
     //Here i am not able to use orderby in this collection Its showing error line
     // Here i need to sort the _availableStocks 
    }
```

My Actual code is:

```
   foreach (var cachedStock in AvailableSelectedStocks)
      {

          if (SelectedStock != null)
          {

            AvailableStocks= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_availableStocks);

            AvailableStocks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(SelectedStock.Casepack.CasePackContents.Count.ToString(), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            //In this above line i am getting the Sort descriptions only i am not getting the datas in the SourceCollection . how can i get values in this Collection

            this.SelectedStocks.Remove(SelectedStock);

            this.RaisePropertyChanged(Member.Of(() => AvailableStocks));

         }
      }
```

Comment: Exception or compiler error? Can you show how is that property being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .OrderBy extension returns an IEnumerable, which is causing your problem. Attempting to sort in the getter is also somewhat bad.

I would look into wrapping your observable collection with ICollectionView

I.e

```
public ICollectionView Stocks { get; private set; }

private readonly ObservableCollection<Stock> stocks;
```

Constructor

```
  stocks = new ObservableCollection<Stock>();
  Stocks = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(stocks);
  Stocks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Where 'Name' is the **name of the Property** of the class Stock that you wish to sort by.

When you add to the observable collection 'stocks', the 'Stocks' ICollectionView will be updated and your view will display the items in the sorted order.

Comment: Thank you for your nice code.I tried your code everything is fine but i have one doubt on this line "Stocks.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); " In this line , the SortDescription() only accepts string values to order elements Its not accepting my class values.

Comment: You specify the name of the property, for example, if you have a class with the properties 'Name' and 'Code', and you want to sort by the 'Name' property, you specify "Name" for the SortDescription. This will then sort your data by that property, in the direction you specify.

Comment: Can you please let me know Where i have to add My _availableStocks in your code

Comment: '_availableStocks' corresponds to the 'stocks' observable collection in my code. This is the collection you add items to. If you are binding a control to the data, you would bind the control's ItemSource to the 'Stocks' ICollectionView. If you are still not sure post some more of your code and I'll change the example.

Comment: Hi Wdavo! I edited my post again by using your code . can you please check it and let me know How can i get the values in that collection...  In that SortDescriptions i gave the value which is used to sort the Data... My Data is actually a row . In that row i sorted the rows by using one column count but the row values where should i get in that collection. Or Shall we need to bind the datas in the collection first and after we have to sort?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
return new ObservableCollection<Stock>(_availableStocks.OrderBy(z=>.Casepack.CasePackContents).ToList());
```

Comment: When I am using this same format i am getting empty collection

Comment: Yes! _availableStocks having count = 0

Comment: I want to convert IEnumurable to Observable Collection without creating new instance of Observable collection

Answer (score 0):

If your property type is an Observable collection, you'll need to return an Observable collection too:

```
if (_availableStocks == null)
{
  return null;
}

var orderredStocks = _availableStocks.OrderBy(z => z.Casepack.CasePackContents);
return new ObservableCollection<T>(orderredStocks);
```

Replacing T with your stock type.

Note that everytime you'll access the property, the ordering is going to be performed so it might be a good idea to move this code elsewhere where it is executed once and its result returned by the property.

Comment: I want to convert IEnumurable to Observable Collection without creating new instance oo Observable collection

Comment: @SuryaKavitha You cannot, the linq call returns an IEnumerable that is not an ObservableCollection

Comment: When i create a new instance for observable collection, My colection and new collection both will empty

Answer (score -1):

OrderBy() is Extension method on System.Linq.

You need to using System.Lninq on top pf your class.

Put

using System.Lninq;

Please make sure on that one first.

You can create new instance of  Observable Collection by...

```
return new ObservableCollection<SOMETYPE>(_availableStocks.OrderBy(z=>.Casepack.CasePackContents).ToList());
```

Comment: I want to convert IEnumurable to Observable Collection without creating new instance oo Observable collection